# How do I mount ejected external USB flash storage?

Tags: macos, terminal, storage, usb

Suppose that we connect our flash USB drive to a MacBook, then eject this storage from Finder sidebar. Now I want to remount this storage without unplugging and replugging it into the computer, but the disk is no longer listed with `diskutil list` command.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you describe was initially the intention for me to write an app that allows you to manage your drives from the menu bar. It is called Mountain and you can get it [here](http://getmountainapp.com/).

Hope you enjoy it!!

**UPDATE:** The only way to re-mount ejected external USB flash drives is to unload and load the USB mass storage kernel extension:

```
kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext
```

Followed by:

```
kextload /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext
```

Be aware that this will re-mount ALL external USB drives..

Comment: Can your app re-mount ejected drive?

Comment: Mountain can re-mount unmounted drives. It is in general not possible to re-mounted ejected drives. That is why Mountain only unmounts drives and does not eject them. Unmounted drives can be either unplugged or re-mounted.

Comment: The only way to re-mount ejected external USB flash drives is to unload and load the USB mass storage kernel extension: kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext; kextload /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext Be aware that this will re-mount ALL external USB drives...

Comment: @JannisLinxweiler The tip doesn't work anymore for Sierra (`(libkern/kext) not found`). Do you know if the mechanism is the same and if the extension has just another name?

Answer (score 1):

You mount devices using:

```
diskutil mountDisk device
```

where device can be a

- device node: `/dev/disk2`
- disk identifier: `disk1s7`
- volume mount point: `/Volumes/Macintosh HD`

For those that like the graphical **Disk Utility.app**, it also shows a connected drive that happens to not be mounted and you are able to mount ejected disks again from there as well.

Comment: It looks like USB flash drives are a special case, which I hadn't noticed before. After ejecting the last volume the disk is removed from the device list, unlike most hard drives. However, using `diskutil unmount` or `diskutil unmountDisk` instead will unmount the volume(s) but leave the device connected for remounting.

Answer (score -1):

## Disk Utility

No need for the commandline here. Open Disk Utility (/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility), select your drive and click Mount.

[image: Disk Utility]

*image comes from wikipedia*

Comment: The question is about _ejected_ NOT _unmounted_ or _dismounted_ drives...

Comment: @PatrickT, you CAN mount ejected drives within Disk Utility.

Comment: After the SD/USB is ejected, it doesn't show in the Disk Utility: I tested it before commenting. Unless there's an extra step not detailed here, your suggestion did not work for me. Thanks though ;-)

Comment: Here I have detailed an Automator solution based on other users' comments:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62478/re-mount-ejected-sd-card-without-reinserting/149166#149166

Comment: @PatrickT, blame on me. you are right. It does work with USB hard-drives (which I tested) but does not work with USB-thumb drives. Sorry for my ignorance.