# Problem with kextunload SD card remount

Tags: external-disk, sd-card, kernel-extensions

So I got one of those SD card flush mounts, but it occasionally self ejects. I'm trying to solve that via kextunload given on this [page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62478/re-mount-ejected-sd-card-without-reinserting)

Entering:

```
sudo kextunload -b /System/Library/Extensions/AppleSDXC.kext
```

Returns:

```
(kernel) Kext /System/Library/Extensions/AppleSDXC.kext not found for unload request.
Failed to unload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleSDXC.kext - (libkern/kext) not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `bundle identifier` when using the `-b` argument. 
In this case, the bundle identifier is `com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC`

`sudo kextunload -b com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC`

*If the same error message is returned, then the kernel extension was not loaded to begin with.*

You can check this information using `kextstat | grep -e SDXC`

Regardless, to find the Bundle ID:

`/System/Library/Extensions/AppleSDXC.kext/Contents/Info.plist` the bundle identifier is stored under the BundleID key:

`<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC</string>`

Answer (score 0):

This  is the version that's working for me.

```
sudo kextunload -b com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC
sudo kextload -b com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC
```