# SD Card missing after sleeping during write?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, sleep-wake, sd-card

I have a flush-mounted 128GB SD card for my Macbook Pro. Had it for a year, never any problems or issues.

Today, while trying to free up some space on my main drive, I was moving a large directory -- 11GB -- onto the SD card, when I had to leave my office.

So, I closed my laptop, thinking the copy operation would just resume when I opened it back up and the machine woke up from sleep...

...But now it says that the SD card was "not ejected properly" (I never ejected it).  And now I can't get it to be recognized, and thus I can't access my data on what I rely on as an extra hard drive.

I tried remounting via the Automator script in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62478/re-mount-ejected-sd-card-without-reinserting/155229#155229), but I see no effect.  I then tried pulling the card out & putting it back in, but to no avail. Tried running Disk Utility, but it just sat there "spinning" and was basically frozen & unresponsive for 5 minutes.

Help?

Comment: Please put your answer that reboot worked. It’s always ok to answer your own question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to simply reboot.  After rebooting, the drive auto-mounted, and all data appeared intact.