# how to re-mount USB drive

Tags: mount, automount

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I mount ejected external USB flash storage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40112/how-do-i-mount-ejected-external-usb-flash-storage)

So, I plugged a USB drive.
Then ejected it.

But it's still connected to my machine.
is there a way to force a re-connect and avoid having to plug it out and plug it in again?

Same goes to a password protected volume on my SSD or HD. It asks me for a password. I cancel. As a result the volume is not mounted. Is there any way to force it to ask me again without rebooting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the USB, you will have to go to the extreme trouble of plugging it out, and then back in i'm afraid

For the SSD, you could try and open up disk utilities, and the volume should be greyed out on the left, all you need to do, it select the volume, then click the mount button on the top. I have done that with a volume on my MBP, but it might be different for a password-protected drive.

Hope this helps!

Rory Costello